# Mapping flat file dates and sql server dates lookup editor

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, date, ssis, etl

I am attempting to import many flat file attributes into a large database table with the restriction that the flat file dates must match the table's dates. I am doing this with visual studio SSIS as there are over 500 files and I need a standardized way of looping through them.The flat files have daily data over 5 years while the table only has about 5 months worth of daily data. A picture of the process is below:

[image]

Both have the proper date format/type however, when I attempt to use the mapping feature of the lookup transformation editor I find that the database date has converted to a `database date [DT_DBDATE]` type while the flat file stays as a `date [DT_DATE]` type.

[image]

Is there a way to cast the date type in the lookup tool? I am also open to using a different visual studio tool if there is another way to go about this. So long as I only get the sub-segment of data from the flat files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

You can solve this by adding a derived column transformation that add a new column with type of `DT_DBDATE` using the following expression

```
(DT_DBDATE)[Date]
```

Or you can use a Data conversion transformation

## Additional Info

According to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types):

- **DT_DBDATE (database date):** *A date structure that consists of year, month, and day.*
- **DT_DATE (date):** *A date structure that consists of year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, and fractional seconds. The fractional seconds have a fixed scale of 7 digits.*
  *The DT_DATE data type is implemented using an 8-byte floating-point number. Days are represented by whole number increments, starting with 30 December 1899, and midnight as time zero. Hour values are expressed as the absolute value of the fractional part of the number. However, a floating point value cannot represent all real values; therefore, there are limits on the range of dates that can be presented in DT_DATE.*
  *On the other hand, DT_DBTIMESTAMP is represented by a structure that internally has individual fields for year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds. This data type has larger limits on ranges of the dates it can present.*

And According to [This Link](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/1387/ssis-to-sql-server-data-type-translations), both data types are stored as `Date` type in SQL Server